# In Rails 6.1 : "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved :Failed to remove the existing associated page."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I want to remove the association between two tables using `Nil` command.

Subject model looks like
subject.rb

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord

has_one :page
# subject has one page

# scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true) }
# scope :invisible, -> { where(visible: false) }
# scope :sorted, -> { order("position ASC") }
# scope :newest_first, -> { order("created_at DESC") } 

scope :visible, lambda  { where(visible: true) }
scope :invisible, lambda  { where(visible: false) }
scope :sorted, lambda { order("position ASC") }
scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") } 
scope :search, lambda { |query| where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%"]) }
```

end
Page Model looks like

page.rb

```
 class Page < ApplicationRecord
 # foreign key
    belongs_to :subject
  end
```

Page migrated file looks like

20210919102818_create_pages.rb

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
def up
 create_table :pages do |t|

    t.integer "subject_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "permalink"
    t.integer "position"
    t.boolean "visible", default:false
    t.timestamps
   end
   add_index :pages, :subject_id
   add_index :pages, :permalink
 end
  def down
    drop_table :pages
   end
 end
```

Subject migrated file looks like

20210919102807_create_subjects.rb

```
    class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|

      t.integer "subject_id"
      t.string "name"
      t.string "permalink"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible", default:false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :pages, :subject_id
    add_index :pages, :permalink
  end
  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end
end
```

The error part for using nil. it is showing

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to remove the existing associated
> page. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.)

Error Picture

[image: Error Part]

Answer (score 2):

The reason, as explained in [this blog](https://andycroll.com/ruby/be-careful-assigning-to-has-one-relations/#in-modern-rails-after-50), is because of a change to Rails 5+, where "belongs_to" have an implied presence validation which prevent it from being set to nil. The [release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes) offer a solution which is

```
belongs_to :subject, optional: true
```

in your case.